# php is not getting any request from ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm working on contact us form to send emails. I have written HTML form to get user details, and performing form validations in contactform.js file. In the same javascript file i've written ajax POST call to call contactus.php located in mail folder.
I have found many similar questions over the internet but the problem is - in my local machine on form Submit button php is getting called, but this is not happening in remote web server.

If I avoid call to contactform.js by removing **class="contactForm"** from my form definition, php is getting called but i loose all the validation. :(
If i call contactform.js by specifying class="contactForm" in form definition then validation are performed nicely but nothing happens on submit since no call to PHP.

Really looking forward to know what am I doing wrong...

Here is my code...

HTML form looks like this:

```html
            <div class="form">
              <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
              <div id="errormessage"></div>
              <form action="contactform/contactform.php" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
                    <div class="validation"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                    <div class="validation"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                  <div class="validation"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                  <div class="validation"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" title="Send Message">Send Message</button></div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

contactform.js

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  //Contact
  $('form.contactForm').submit(function() {
    var f = $(this).find('.form-group'),
      ferror = false,
      emailExp = /^[^\s()<>@,;:\/]+@\w[\w\.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$/i;

    f.children('input').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'email':
            if (!emailExp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'checked':
            if (!i.attr('checked')) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'regexp':
            exp = new RegExp(exp);
            if (!exp.test(i.val())) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') !== undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    f.children('textarea').each(function() { // run all inputs

      var i = $(this); // current input
      var rule = i.attr('data-rule');

      if (rule !== undefined) {
        var ierror = false; // error flag for current input
        var pos = rule.indexOf(':', 0);
        if (pos >= 0) {
          var exp = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
          rule = rule.substr(0, pos);
        } else {
          rule = rule.substr(pos + 1, rule.length);
        }

        switch (rule) {
          case 'required':
            if (i.val() === '') {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;

          case 'minlen':
            if (i.val().length < parseInt(exp)) {
              ferror = ierror = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        i.next('.validation').html((ierror ? (i.attr('data-msg') != undefined ? i.attr('data-msg') : 'wrong Input') : '')).show('blind');
      }
    });
    if (ferror) return false;
    else var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $(form).attr('action'),
      data: str,
      success: function(msg) {
        // alert(msg);
        if (msg == 'OK') {
          $("#sendmessage").addClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").removeClass("show");
          $('.contactForm').find("input, textarea").val("");
        } else {
          $("#sendmessage").removeClass("show");
          $("#errormessage").addClass("show");
          $('#errormessage').html(msg);
        }

      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: Try using `$(this)` or `$('form')` in place of `$(form)` in `url: $(form).attr('action')`. `form` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! $(form).attr('action') worked fine, the problem was with URL, my contactform.js was in different folder than contactus.php.